# Building and publishing iOS Xamarin app on Windows

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I finished my Xamarin app for iOS and I want to publish it on App Store (and test it if possible before that), but I just don't understand AT ALL how to do it.

I built my app on Windows machine, I used my Mac to compile it and to run the simulator.
Now every guide is only about publishing from the Mac, but my whole project is on my Windows machine, and I don't understand at all how to build the app to upload it to store.

(Yes, I have paid Apple developer account.)

What are Apple certificates for? What is provisioning profile? On Microsoft guide page, it says I should archive my app, but it fails and when I try to run the app with "Release" and "iPhone" mode, I get this error message:

```
Could not find any available provisioning profiles for -project name-
```

What does that even mean? :(

"Automatic provisioning" shows this warning for "Release":
[image]

Comment: There is a complete guide that shows this from either VS for Mac or VS17 and 19 from Windows : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows

Comment: "What are Apple certificates for? What is provisioning profile?" - both of these things are **extensively** documented and a core concept in iOS development.  You need to take the time to read up on them if you are developing iOS apps.